# Mobile Menu Positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building out my first template using HubSpot COS. I am trying to implement a mobile menu for my responsive menu.

I have a Menu which I added a custom `class ="custom-menu-primary"`. HubSpot Provided a JS code that I am referencing on the footer of my page. I can see everything is working as expected with the JS but it's the CSS positioning which I cannot figure out.

On mobile my menu is shifting down and I cannot keep if from shifting down. I tried shifting the positioning using a fixed positioning and applying `whitespace: nowrap;` and nothing seems to work as expected. The link to the JS and CSS are here in this HubSpot Article.

What would be the best way to move the mobile-trigger to the very top right of the corner. This is the [link](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=2676636&style_id=hubspot-default-basic&tc_deviceCategory=desktop&template_layout_id=4956239235) to my site.

http://prntscr.com/elwvyi

Answer (score 0):

In your media query section, for class `logo`, add:

```
float:left;
```

For the class `widget-type-space`:

```
display: none;
```

Comment: Thank you was able to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick fix for your issue, the below code solves temporarily.

Please refer bootstrap for the navbar.
[Bootstrap navbar documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
raw-resource?po…fered=true:863
.mobile-trigger {
    display: inline-block !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 7px 10px 8px 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #000000;
}

@media (max-width: 767px)
raw-resource?po…ered=true:1007
.custom-menu-primary.js-enabled .hs-menu-wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image: reference screenshot]